# Как получить случайное время вида hh:mm

Tags: ruby

Собственно нашел ответ на англоязычной версии

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'active_support/all'
def random_hour(from, to)
  (Date.today + rand(from..to).hour + rand(0..60).minutes).to_datetime
end

puts random_hour(10, 15)
```

Вопрос в том, как понимать \принцип работы require я знаю. Вопрос в том, зачем это подключать, что это?\

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'active_support/all'
```

При компиляции этого кода выдает

```
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- active_support/all (LoadError)
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from C:/Users/###/Desktop/RubyProg/OlympProb/2.6/reshenie.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
```

Comment: эти require - классические gem'ы. Если нужно просто показать время как строку, то можно просто так `ruby -e 'puts rand(0..24).to_s + ":" + rand(0..60).to_s'`. А с гемами разберитесь, если нужен руби.

Comment: В принципе как вариант. Но все таки интересно в что не так с вышеуказанным кодом.

Разве это все не входит в стандартную сборку(sdk)?

Comment: понятие "стандартная сборка" - очень размытое. Но боюсь, что как раз у Вас второй пакет как раз не входит. Установить его можно по разному. Либо сделать себе гем файл и тогда руби по Вашей команде все само соберет (и это правильный путь), либо пакетным менеджером доустановить гемы.

Comment: Решил проблему немного модернизировав ваше предложение.
` x=rand(0..24).to_s.rjust(2,'0') + ":" + rand(0..60).to_s.rjust(2,'0')`

Comment: Еще один ,возможно, глупый вопрос, как реализовать регулярками поиск по времени в виде строк?
Если в перле это делать , то должно выглядеть это должно примерно так /\d{16..19}:\d{30}/ ибо неважно, строка или число это.

Comment: регулярка неверная. Скорее всего нужна как минимум такая `\d{1,2}:\d{2}`. Правда она пропустит и `99:99`... можно переписать так `[0-2]?[0-9]:[0-5][0-9]`. Она сильно лучше, но пропустит `29:59`.

Comment: Это тогда регулярка для числовых переменных же.
Возможно ли как нибудь выполнить данную операцию без костылей в виде перебивки строки в массив .partition'ом([hh, ":",mm]), а затем переводить 1 и 3 элемент в число

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для генерации случайного времени и вообще для генерации разнообразной информации, лучше воспользоваться специализированным гемом вроде [faker](https://github.com/stympy/faker#fakertime)

```
require 'faker'

puts Faker::Time.between(
       Time.new(2016, 7, 15, 0, 0, 0),
       Time.new(2016, 7, 15, 23, 59, 59))
```

Чтобы воспользоваться примером выше, вам потребуется установить гем faker

```
gem install activesupport
```

В приведенном вами примере active_support/all скорее всего потребовался для метода `to_datetime`. Это один из компонентов фреймворка Rails, совершенно избыточный для такого небольшого примера. Однако, так как Rails очень популярен и многие разработчики его хорошо знают, очень часто используют его компоненты/гемы для создания каких-то быстрых решений. Чтобы установить active_support, вам потребуется выполнить команду

```
gem install activesupport
```

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'active_support/all'
```

Что это? **Плохой пример загрузки гема [Active Support](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activesupport).**

Это то, из-за чего у *чисел* **внезапно** оказываются методы `hour`/`hours`, `minutes` и подобные. Но беда в том, что **загружается далеко не только это**. Эта строчка загружает **вообще весь Active Support**. А это немаленький гем.

Эти методы в самом Ruby отсутствуют. Попробуйте вычислить в чистом `irb` выражение `5.hours`. Ба-бах, `NoMethodError`. А с ActiveSupport работает, потому что в нём **дописаны** (monkeypatched) стандартные классы. Значит, мы имеем дело с разделом ["Core Extensions" (`core_ext`)](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext). Методы возникли у **чисел**, так что, похоже, что это расширение [`numeric`](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric). Дальше очевидно — методы про время, так что нужен [файл `time.rb`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/time.rb).

Зная это, можно составить куда более "узкий" и быстрый `require`:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/numeric/time'
```

Зачем? Смотрим [гайды Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#stand-alone-active-support):

> In order to have a near-zero default footprint, Active Support does not load anything by default. It is broken in small pieces so that you can load just what you need
>
> Чтобы иметь почти нулевое потребление памяти, Active Support по умолчанию ничего не загружает. Он разбит на маленькие кусочки, чтобы вы могли загрузить только то, что вам нужно